# Default parameters defeated by the out keyword

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I have written a generic enum `TryParse` method which I would like to use with optional parameters, but because it contains the `out` keyword, it turns out that this is not possible.

Here is a code example:

```
public static class Enum<T>
{
  public static bool TryParse(string value, bool ignoreCase = true, out T returnedValue)
  {
    //Not really relevant to the question, but here for completeness.
    try
    {
      returnedValue = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, ignoreCase);
      return true;
    }
    catch
    {
      returnedValue = default(T);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Sadly, this isn't valid as I get that familiar error:

```
Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters
```

Normally, this would make sense, but not here. I believe that the language should be 'smart' enough to determine that this is alright - that the `out` keyword **must** be last, and that it cannot have a default value. For note, this is what happens if you try to put a default:

```
A ref or out parameter cannot have a default value
```

Has anyone come across this themselves? If so, how have they remedied this? If not, should I bring this up on Microsoft Connect?

I do realise that, if this doesn't work, then I'll have to create one more method, but without the `ignoreCase` param, and then simply do a single line return, but pass `true` in for the `ignoreCase`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why must the out param be last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is really in the ordering. Try this:

```
public static bool TryParse(string value,
                            out T returnedValue,
                            bool ignoreCase = true)
```

`out` parameters **don't** have to be last - `params` parameters do. (And they can still come after optional parameters.)

Comment: I won't lie to you Jon, this looks really _really_ wrong! :) I did see a comment (now deleted) by @Sayeed which proposes this, but doesn't this seem at all weird to you? Maybe I'm so used to seeing the `out` param as the last param I never even questioned that it didn't have to be the last one.

Comment: @Dan: It's slightly odd, but I wouldn't say "wrong". I rarely see out parameters other than for the TryXXX pattern, to be honest...

Answer (score 3):

How about doing it *à l'ancienne*:

```
public static bool TryParse(string value, out T returnedValue)
{
    return TryParse(value, true, out returnedValue);
}

public static bool TryParse(string value, bool ignoreCase, out T returnedValue)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Aye, I already mentioned that as a possible solution (see last couple of lines), but it's just not "nice", given the capabilities of the language.

Comment: Oops, missed that part. Quite honestly optional parameters are not one of my favourite language features :-)